# Evaluating polynomials - floating point or optimization issue?

Tags: floating-point

From Numerical Recipes:

> We assume that you know enough never to evaluate a polynomial this way:
>   p=c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*x*x+c[3]*x*x*x+c[4]*x*x*x*x; 
>   ...

Obviously I don't know enough...

Is this only an optimization issue or is it also a floating point arithmetic issue and why?

Comment: If the document you refer too is http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-3.pdf , then you simply should keep reading after the scary sentence. The authors do not assume at all that the reader knows enough to … but explain what they mean over the next couple of paragraphs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can compute `p=c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*x*x+c[3]*x*x*x+c[4]*x*x*x*x;` as:

```
p=c[0]+(c[1]+(c[2]+(c[3]+c[4]*x)*x)*x)*x;
```

There are much fewer multiplications in the second form. This second form is called “Horner's”.

> Is this only an optimization issue or is it also a floating point arithmetic issue and why?

It is mostly an optimization issue. However, some modern processors have a floating-point operation to do a multiplication and an addition in a single instruction without intermediate rounding for the multiplication, and while the benefit that most programmers see is still optimization, it also means that the result is more accurate.

Horner's form is very well-adapted for computation with this [fused-multiply-add instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation).

---

Finally, I should point out for the sake of completeness that modern processors can be even more efficient if the polynomial is presented to them in a form with more parallelism. See for instance [Estrin's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme) or [this blog post](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/9/17/playing-with-the-cpu-pipeline) for a down-to-earth explanation. Your book is not alluding to the requirement of knowing about Estrin's scheme. It is only alluding to the requirement of knowing about Horner's scheme.

Comment: Are there also rounding issues which could affect the answer either way?

Comment: @ClickRick There is nothing more I can say than “it also means that the result is more accurate” already in my answer.

Comment: I was thinking more whether there could be some pathological case which would produce *entirely* the wrong answer if using the form shown in the OP, perhaps by a large positive term and a large negative term cancelling each other out, but by dwarfing another term leave a (wrong) result of zero. Perhaps the subject for a different question.

Comment: @ClickRick Yes, it is a question you should ask. I would be interested in the answer to that. Note that there are several ways to evaluate the human-readable form `c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*x*x+c[3]*x*x*x+c[4]*x*x*x*x`. When `x` is small, the best evaluation would be doing the additions from right to left, in order to limit absorption issues. If so implemented, I would expect the accuracy to be similar. This is easy to measure empirically with exhaustive testing on floats, using long doubles as reference.

Comment: Besides Horner's and Estrin's schemes, one can also evaluate polynomials in factored form.  For a quartic, this looks like `c*((x+a1)*x+a0)*((x+b1)*x+b0)`.  Note: same throughput as Horner's, but with significantly lower latency on a pipelined architecture.  The gotcha is that if the polynomial isn't well behaved, the process of factoring (and rounding the factors) may introduce troublesome perturbations.